# Check how long has passed since the last click Expo (React Native)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to detect how long it has been since the user interacted with my app. This means how long has passed since the user last clicked, scrolled, etc. What is the best way to do this and how should I go about it. There is nothing similar that I can find. I want to use this to change the UI. For example, if the user doesn't do anything for 10 seconds, I want to reduce component opacity.

Comment: You can either save the data locally or in store it in a db, ie. `{ lastClick: timestamp }`. Locally you wouldn't need the user to have an account, but persistence could be an issue. Then you can use that data to conditionally render whatever you want to render.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to measure how long it's been since the user interacted with the application. I don't know how to get the ```timestamp```

Comment: You'd need a function that sent the timestamp to wherever you are storing the data when the user clicked/pressed/did whatever action you were tracking. Then you could use that data for your comparison on the next event

Comment: you can also use React Native's AppState https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate if you wan't to know when the user is actively using the app or if its in the background

Comment: Data storage is not my problem, I know how to do it. My problem is I don't know how to make the function which will provide me with the ```timestamp``` value

Comment: As the answer below mentions, use the javascript [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to capture the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just use Date.now() and save it using whatever local storage you want. Likely the async-storage library. The built in Date.now() function will just give you the number of milliseconds that have passed since Jan 01, 1970. And its pretty decent for measuring time lapses.

Comment: How can I check for user interactions with the UI?

Comment: Add a TouchableOpacity element that wraps your app with an onPress prop that restarts a timer. Then setup a timer using setTimeout or similar method that executes a callback after x number of minutes that reduces the opacity.